# Null sequences. Proving a sequence is null

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that $(n+1)^{1/2}  -  n^{1/2}$ is null. I know there's a similar question already posted but I need to prove this stating rules etc.

What I've done already is use difference of 2 squares to get to:

$1/[(n+1)^{1/2} + n^{1/2}]$ which I'm sure is near the end. Do I need to use the Squeeze Rule?

Comment: "Squeeze Rule"? This sounds a bit gruesome ;)

Comment: There's a result that states that if $a_n$ is a sequence with $a_n = \frac{1}{b_n}$ for each $n$ then $a_n \to 0$ if and only if $\left| b_n \right| \to \infty$. It's easy to prove and is very useful here.

Comment: You are not using squeeze theorem here.

Comment: Multiplying by its 'conjugate' (n+1)^1/2+n^1/2 gives 1. but then we get to divide by the 'conjugate' which clearly goes to infinity and thus we get 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $a_n=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$, and we want to show  that $\lim a_n=0$.

Let see, what is $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$:

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

So, when $n\to\infty$, we get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of a null sequence, if E (Epsilon) > 0 then there exists a number X such that absolute value of  |an|  < E for all n>X
Here an = (n+1)^1/2 - ( n)^1/2
Let Epsilon E > 0 then 
  |(n+1)^1/2 - ( n)^1/2| < E
(n+1)^1/2 - ( n)^1/2 < E
(n+1)^1/2 < E + (n)^1/2
squaring both sides gives
n+1 < E^2 +2E(n)^1/2 +n
n-n +1 < E^2  + 2E(n)^1/2
-2E (n)^1/2 n>(2/E^2 -2)^2
so according to the def of null seq |an|  < E for all n>X
here X =(2/E^2 -2)^2
so n>X proved it is a null seq

Comment: Please write your answer clearly, use the math formatting. Your answer is unclear.